# How to rewrite this function to avoid addeventlistener firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I need some help rewriting this function. I don't have anymore ideas.

The function starts at onclick button.

What am I doing wrong? Should I attach a class to know when the button was clicked first time?

I have tried anything I could think of, create global variable to see if the main function was accessed before and if it was, it would remove event listener. I attached a class when the function was first time access. I ran out of ideas.

Thank you for your help.

```
function activareEvent(cauta){
  if(flag==1)
  {
    rezultat = rezultat1;
  }
  cautare = document.getElementById("cautare"+cauta);
  innermenu = document.getElementById("innermenu"+cauta);
  myDropdown=document.getElementById("myDropdown"+cauta);
  categoriego=document.getElementById("categoriego"+cauta);
  hiddencat=document.getElementById("hiddencat"+cauta);
  countscroll=0;
  counter=0;
  var mouseovr = function(e){
    if(flag==1)
    {
      rezultat = rezultat1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < rezultat.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById(i).style.background = "";
    }
    countscroll=e.target.id;
    document.getElementById(countscroll).style.background = "#ddd";
  }
  innermenu.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseovr, false);
  var clickasc = function(e){
    if(flag==1)
    {
      rezultat = rezultat1;
    }
    categoriego.innerHTML=rezultat[countscroll][2];

    eacha=[];
    rezultata=[];
    counter=0;
    for (i = 0; i < rezultat.length; i++) {
      if (rezultat[i][0]==(rezultat[countscroll][1]))
      {
    eacha[i] = "<a id="+counter+">"+rezultat[i][2]+"("+rezultat[i][1]+")"+"</a>";
    rezultata.push([rezultat[i][0],rezultat[i][1], rezultat[i][2]]);
    counter++;
      }


    }
    if(rezultata.length>0){
      innermenu.innerHTML =eacha.join("");
      rezultat=rezultata;
    }
    else{
      hiddencat.value=rezultat[countscroll][1];
      innermenu.innerHTML = "";
      myDropdown.classList.toggle("show");
      document.getElementById(0).style.background = "#ddd";
      rezultat=[];
      countscroll=0;
      counter=0;
      innermenu.removeEventListener('keydown', mouseovr);
      innermenu.removeEventListener('keydown', clickasc);
      cautare.removeEventListener('keydown', cautaresc);
    }
  }
  innermenu.addEventListener('click', clickasc, false);
  var cautaresc = function(e){
    if(flag==1)
    {
      rezultat = rezultat1;
    }
    document.getElementById(countscroll).style.background = "";
    if(e.which == 38){
      countscroll--;
      if(countscroll<0)
      {
    countscroll=0;
      }
    }
    if(e.which == 40){
      countscroll++;
      if(countscroll==rezultat.length)
      {
    countscroll=rezultat.length-1;
      }
    }
    document.getElementById(countscroll).style.background = "#ddd";
    if(e.which == 13){
      categoriego.innerHTML=rezultat[countscroll][2];
      eacha=[];
      rezultata=[];
      counter=0;
      for (i = 0; i < rezultat.length; i++) {
    if (rezultat[i][0]==(rezultat[countscroll][1]))
    {
      eacha[i] = "<a id="+counter+">"+rezultat[i][2]+"("+rezultat[i][1]+")"+"</a>";
      rezultata.push([rezultat[i][0],rezultat[i][1], rezultat[i][2]]);
      counter++;
    }
      }
      if(rezultata.length>0){
    innermenu.innerHTML =eacha.join("");
    document.getElementById(0).style.background = "#ddd";
    rezultat=rezultata;
    console.log(counter);
      }
      else{
    hiddencat.value=rezultat[countscroll][1];
    innermenu.innerHTML = "";
    myDropdown.classList.toggle("show");
    rezultat=[];
    countscroll=0;
    counter=0;
    innermenu.removeEventListener('keydown', mouseovr);
    innermenu.removeEventListener('keydown', clickasc);
    cautare.removeEventListener('keydown', cautaresc);
      }
    }
  }
  cautare.addEventListener('keydown', cautaresc, false);
}
```

Comment: 117 lines of code is not exactly a [MCVE], can you include only the parts of the code relevant to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

this function is massive, I'm not very experienced but I would say that a function should be maybe 15 lines MAYBE 20, there is too much going on here to easily debug your code. maybe extract some helper functions from your main function. Also all those If/else statements make your code hard to extend, you might consider writing that logic onto the class rather than the function implementation. I'm not too clear on what you need here but I'm going to give it a shot anyway:

attach the event listeners to a custom class with a flag property, then check for the property within the function

**class definition**

```
export class foo {
  constructor(HTMLElemenet){
    this.HTMLElement = HTMLElement
  }
  flag = true
  attachEventListener(){
    if(this.flag){
      //just an example, you can add any event listener here
      this.HTMLElement.addEventListener('click',()=>{})
      this.flag = false
    }
}
```

**code**

```
var baz = new foo
baz.attachEventListener(docuement.getElementById('bar'))
```